# Intellij IDEA static import auto complete won't show other imports

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mockito

I want to import the `verify` function from Mockito using a static import but when I do the shortcut to import `verify` IntelliJ won't show the package that I need.
[image]

It just shows those imports but I needed this one `import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;`
which I had to look for. The picture below is from a YouTuber that have more method to import from, how can I have my one like his, or at least have the ones I need?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chk if below is added in your pom---

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```